# Spring REST API architecture

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I recently started to learn REST API and have already encountered problems of architecture. In order not to scare a lot of code, I will try to describe it in brief. I have such a structure of domain objects: `User -> TaskCard -> Task`. That is, the user has a list of task cards, and each task card has a list of tasks. So, the first doubt I had in the controller. Here it is necessary to clarify that I use Spring Security and in each method of the controller I get a user in order to validate it. Also I use Spring Data JPA. That is, for example, in order to prevent the fact that one user is trying to change the task card of another user. Here's a TaskCardController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("taskcards")
public class TaskCardController {
    private TaskCardService taskCardService;

    @Autowired
    public TaskCardController(TaskCardService taskCardService) {
        this.taskCardService = taskCardService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<TaskCardDto> getAllTaskCards(@CurrentUser User user) {
        return user.getTaskCards()
                   .stream()
                   .map(TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE::toDto)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public TaskCardDto getTaskCard(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(user.getTaskCard(id));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public TaskCardDto createTaskCard(@CurrentUser User user, @RequestBody TaskCardDto taskCardDto) {
        TaskCard taskCard = TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(taskCardDto);
        return TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(taskCardService.saveTaskCard(taskCard, user));
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public TaskCardDto updateTaskCard(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody TaskCardDto replacementDto) {
        TaskCard existing = user.getTaskCard(id);
        TaskCard replacement = TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(replacementDto);
        return TaskCardMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(taskCardService.updateTaskCard(existing, replacement));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void deleteTaskCard(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        taskCardService.deleteTaskCard(user.getTaskCard(id));
    }
}
```

(`@CurrentUser` is a wrapper over `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. That is, here spring security sends me the user who caused this request).

As you can see, I don't use the service to get user cards, but instead use a real user instance. So, is it bad to do this? I'm not sure what I'm doing correctly because everyone uses services everywhere, but I only use it in two methods. I do this because in my opinion it is better, because if I did it through services, I would have to create new methods like `findAllForUser()` or `findAllByIdAndUserIs()` (this is for get with id). So, the question is, am I doing the right thing, or should I still use services in each controller method? Here it should also be noted that controllers are easier to test if they use services, since I can just make a mock of the service, while it will be difficult for a user. But when using the services, there is another problem: interacting with tasks. Now to get tasks I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("taskcards/{cardId}/tasks")
public class TaskController {
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    public TaskController(TaskService taskService) {
        this.taskService = taskService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<TaskDto> getAllTasks(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId) {
        return user.getTaskCard(cardId)
                   .getTasks()
                   .stream()
                   .map(TaskMapper.INSTANCE::toDto)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public TaskDto getTask(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId, @PathVariable Long id) {
        Task task = user.getTaskCard(cardId).getTask(id);
        return TaskMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(task);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public TaskDto createTask(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId, @RequestBody TaskDto taskDTO) {
        Task task = TaskMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(taskDTO);
        TaskCard taskCard = user.getTaskCard(cardId);
        return TaskMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(taskService.saveTask(task, taskCard));
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public TaskDto updateTask(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId,
                              @PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody TaskDto replacementDto) {
        Task existing = user.getTaskCard(cardId).getTask(id);
        Task replacement = TaskMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(replacementDto);
        return TaskMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(taskService.updateTask(existing, replacement));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void deleteTask(@CurrentUser User user, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        taskService.deleteTask(user.getTaskCard(cardId).getTask(id));
    }
}
```

As you can see here, I work on the same principle, that is, I get data from a real user instance. And here it will be really difficult to add services, because in this case you will first need to find the task card in the database, and check whether it belongs to this user, and then find the necessary task. That is for example for the GET method with id I would have to create the following method for the service and repository `findByIdAndTaskCardIdAndTaskCarduser()`. And it's just awful, I have to make additional requests to the database and create additional methods for the repository and service. In General, please tell me how to make a better architecture? I'm not very good at REST API yet so I don't know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
should I still use services in each controller method?
```

it's always recommended that we need to use the services in order to process the business logic. At this point, you can think that it will not needed because of you have just limited API calls but think, if you have any new requirements need to be done with same Rest Controllers and you are managing every thing in controller class itself which will be looks like big mess and its not recommended.

We need to use services in order to make controller class lighter and better. But you don't need have service for each controller class.(at least in my opinion)

I hope this helps :)